# JMeter 3.3 - Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: email, jmeter, smtp, gmail

I am new to jmeter and trying to send an email using Jmeter and SMTP.

Here is my sampler:

[image]

this is the error results:

```
Thread Name: REST example 1-3
Sample Start: 2018-01-15 14:34:54 CET
Load time: 21003
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 173
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 173
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

after changing the gmail server I am getting a similar error, as below:

```
Thread Name: REST example 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-01-15 15:32:45 CET
Load time: 21104
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 173
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 173
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.googlemail.com, port: 587

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried unchecking enforce starttls

Thanks

Comment: are you using JMeter 3.3 (previous version had issues)?

Comment: yes it's version 3.3

Comment: Do you get same error with Enforce StartTLS checkbox unchecked?

Comment: yes the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try connecting to test connectivity to `smtp.gmail.com:587` using [telnet tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) or equivalent. If you cannot - it might be the case you're behind the corporate firewall and you'll need to "tell" JMeter to use your corporate proxy.

For [HTTP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) add the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
https.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
https.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
```

for SMTP set the [following property](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy):

```
socksProxyHost=your_proxy_host
```

You can also pass them to JMeter startup script via [-D command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -DsocksProxyHost=your_proxy_host
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

Comment: yes, I am behind the firewall cause I cannot telnet, how can I tell jmeter to use the corporate firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Your server link is wrong, instead of `smtp.gmail.com` use `smtp.googlemail.com`

There were [changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) in SMTP Sampler in latest versions, be sure to use latest 3.3 version.
Also see [full SMTP tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter).

Also this error can be due to gmail [blocked your IP](http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/61-sending-with-gmail-doesnt-work)

> Google's security system has blocked the IP of your server ..
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host." then you might be entering this case scenario

Comment: thanks @user7294900, I changed the server and followed the link but I am getting the same error, will update my question soon